# Link to Wordpress 'latest posts' page when using static front page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a static page set as front page in Wordpress, instead of default 'latests posts' page. However, I would still like to be able to navigate to 'latests posts' page, but I'm not sure how to access it.

I'm doing this since I want my top navigation to be HOME (static page, front page), BLOG (latest posts), ABOUT (static page), and so on.

Since this is my custom template, I'm ok with writing PHP to achieve this if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, simple RTM case: http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_SubPanel

Comes out that another page can be designated as posts page, and in that case that page disregards custom template and essentially becomes new 'latest posts' page.

Comment: Yes, but can this be done **without** using a subdirectory / Page?
(I want to do exactly this, but I don't want my latest posts dropped into a /blog subdirectory.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put some PHP in that uses "the loop". See here for more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! While "the loop" wasn't direct solution for this, I'm already using it to build custom list of post titles.